# Можно ли в d3js с помощью Collapsible Tree сделать две исходящие стрелки?

Tags: treeview, d3.js, дерево

Есть библиотека d3.js для построения интерактивного дерева:
http://charts.animateddata.co.uk/datavistree/

Можно ли с ее помощью сделать для узла две исходящие линии, которые потом сливаются в одну?

Более подробно описал во вложенной картинке:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Еще два примера на подобные деревья:
http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033